# Google App Engine app.yaml match all PHP files and match all HTML files and serve respectively

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I'm using Google App Engine with PHP.  I want all `HTML` files in the folder `Client_Pages` to be recognized and served as static files, and all the `PHP` files in the same folder to be recognized and served as script files.  Here is what the `app.yaml` file looks like:

```
application: myappname
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: index.php

- url: /Client_Pages/*.php
  script: /Client_Pages/*.php

- url: /Client_Pages/*.html
  static_dir: Client_Pages/*.html
```

I guess the `asterisk` doesn't work as a wildcard in `app.yaml`? I've tried using:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)
  script: Client_Pages/\1
```

But that doesn't work.  I don't even know what all the symbols mean, so I'm just hacking around, hoping something will work.  I don't want to do that, but I can't find documentation for what all those symbols do.

This will work for a specific page:

```
- url: /Client_Pages/InputForm.php
  script: /Client_Pages/InputForm.php
```

I could put a line in my `app.yaml` file for every single page in my website, but I'd rather find a different way.

Oh wait! Hold on!  This works for loading my PHP files:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)
  script: \1
```

So what does the `\1` mean?  Or where is a good reference?

Okay, so the above works for `php` pages, but this will ***NOT*** work for HTML pages, why?

```
- url: /(.+\.html)
  static_dir: \1
```

I got something to work.  This will load both my `PHP` and `HTML` pages:

```
- url: /(.+\.php)
  script: \1

- url: /Client_Pages
  static_dir: Client_Pages
```

So I found a solution, but I still have absolutely no idea why it works, or what the symbols mean.

I apologize for finding a partial answer to my own question in the process of posting it, but if someone could explain why it works, I'll give you the points you deserve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) regular expression reference is probably easiest to follow and closest to what's happening here, along with the [app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/appconfig) reference.

Essentially, the ( ) in the regular expression specify a grouping (also known as back referencing), and your regular expression can have many groups. The \1 is a reference to the first group, \2 would be the second group etc etc. This lets you extract out the value that matched the regular expression and use that value for selecting the script or static resource.

So basically for the regular expression

```
/(.+\.php)
```

is saying 'make the first group any value that matches the regular expression .+\.php'. The value that matches the regular expression can be retrieved by using the \1 which specified the first group.

So the value /foobar.php matches the regular expression .+.php and the value of \1 becomes foobar.php because of the ( ) around the regular expression.

Slightly more complicated:

```
/(.+)/(.+)\.php$
```

The value of /foo/bar.php would match this regular expression, \1 would equal 'foo' [as it's the first group in the regular expression] and \2 would equal 'bar' [as it's the second group].

Note that this regular expression would not match /foobar.php.

You could also do something like this so that the URL doesn't need to have the .php in it.

```
- url: /(.+)
  script: \1.php
```

By using static_dir your removing the need for grouping, as it will match to any file that is in the directory.

If you wanted to match just the *.html files you could use

```
- url: /Client_Pages/(.*)\.html$
  static_files: Client_Pages/\1.html
  upload: Client_Pages/*\.html$
```

Finally, the thing to remember with app.yaml as it processes the rules from top to bottom, and the first match is executed and processing stops.

So an app.yaml like

```
- url: /.*
  script: index.php

- url: /(.+)\.html
  static_dir: html_pages
```

would **always** execute index.php as the first regular expression would match any incomming URL.

Comment: I tried using `static_files:` with `upload:` and just `html` files, and it stopped serving some `css` files I had in a sub directory.  So, I guess I'll just keep using `static_dir` to recognize all html and css files, and serve them.  `php` files won't respond to anything but the `script:` handler.

Comment: just add css to the regex then (css|html)$ etc. Take a look at the wordpress app.yaml -> https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress

Comment: Thanks, I saw this: `- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$`  Is there an advantage to configuring it that way?  I'm at a loss for understanding the purpose of the configuration.  If the configuration just matches everything anyway, then what's the point?

Comment: it only matches files that end with those extensions, not 'everything'.

Comment: Yes, true.  I'm just curious to consider advantages/disadvantages  between:  `- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$`  and `- url: /Client_Pages
  static_dir: Client_Pages`.

Comment: one serves everything, one gives you more control - say for example you have jpg files in the same folder that you want to serve with different cache headers etc