# google app engine joomla links not loading

Tags: php, google-app-engine, joomla

I have recently followed the great instructions on the following link to get running joomla 3.2.1 on google app engine
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=828565&p=3114492

I am still running this locally but have come up against an issue with loading static files.

None of my static links load despite having the correct url. Here is a snippet from the SDK log

```
Python command: /usr/bin/python2.7
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:23,676 devappserver2.py:675] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-03-14 01:10:23,690 api_server.py:341] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:23,696 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:51014
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:23,702 dispatcher.py:176] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:23,709 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8001
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,491 module.py:612] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6371
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,510 module.py:612] default: "GET /templates/protostar/css/template.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,511 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,518 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,519 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/core.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,520 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,522 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/tabs-state.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,523 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/caption.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,524 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/mootools-core.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,524 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,525 module.py:612] default: "GET /templates/protostar/js/template.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,645 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,649 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,654 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/tabs-state.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,658 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/mootools-core.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,662 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/core.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,666 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/system/js/caption.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,670 module.py:612] default: "GET /joomla/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2014-03-14 01:10:29,692 module.py:612] default: "GET /media/jui/fonts/IcoMoon.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

all of these urls correspond exactly to the file structure on the site but they all come back as 404 errors on google console!

The identical files work perfectly on Mamp.

my app.yaml files is like this

```
    application: demo-test
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: joomla/\1
  upload: joomla/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true
  secure: always

## Admin  
- url: /administrator(.+)
  script: joomla/administrator\1
  secure: always

## Asset folders
- url: /media
  static_dir: joomla/media
  application_readable: true

- url: /images
  static_dir: joomla/images
  application_readable: true

## Template folders
- url: /templates
  static_dir: joomla/templates
  application_readable: true

- url: /administrator/templates
  static_dir: joomla/administrator/templates
  application_readable: true

## SEO robots
- url: /robots.txt
  script: joomla/robots.txt 

## Site access
- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: joomla/index.php
  secure: always
```

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The incoming URL for the 404's starts with /joomla/ so you need to take that into account in your handler when writing the regular expression.

Try something like

```
handlers:
- url: /joomla/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: joomla/\1
  upload: joomla/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true
  secure: always
```

Also do you really only want to serve these over HTTPS? If not, then remove the secure: always line.

Comment: thanks Stuart, it works well although i am not quite sure why. With the existing regEx I thought this would search for these files from this point and therefore including the joomla directory already..?

Comment: you need to lookup how the back referencing works (the \1) to understand why it didnt't work. I have a previous SO post that answers it pretty well you should be able to find.

Comment: I looked at your post here, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184211/google-app-engine-app-yaml-match-all-php-files-and-match-all-html-files-and-serv), the (the \1) part is much clearer. you've said to look at, (https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/wordpress), in your comments. My app.yaml file was based on the joomla version of this, (http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=828565&p=3114492). In the WP version they don't add '/wordpress/' in the url. Do we need to add joomla or wp in a separate folder?